# How to access environment variables in sbt assembly jar?

Tags: java, jar, sbt, environment-variables, sbt-assembly

I have an sbt project that spins up a server on a specified port. Here is related excerpt from `build.sbt`:

`port in container.Configuration := sys.env.getOrElse("MY_VAR_SEARCH_PORT", 8080).toString.toInt`

When I run the project from sbt, `$MY_VAR_SEARCH_PORT` gets picked up, and all is good.

However, for prod I use sbt-assembly and run a jar in a docker container, so the launch command looks like this:

`docker run -it -p 80:80 -e MY_VAR_SEARCH_PORT=80 mydockerhubrepo/myimageid /docker-entrypoint.sh java -Djava.io.tmpdir=/tmp/jetty -Drun.mode=production -Denv=prod -jar /usr/local/jetty/start.jar`

I can see that var gets passed to the container, but it is not being picked up by the jar, as it spins up a server on default port.

What would be a good way to make sbt-assembly jar access environment variables? Or maybe I can pass this var as java argument - then, how to access it from build.sbt file?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: I posted an answer. Can you please kindly let me know if that answer worked for you. Or feel free to post your own :)

Answer (score 1):

Move java startup command to a shell script that would access env vars without a problem:

1. In your project, add api_startup.sh:
   `#!/bin/sh
   echo "API startup script running... with ENV=$ENV" 
   java -Djava.io.tmpdir=/tmp/jetty -Drun.mode=production -Denv=$ENV -Drun.port=$MY_VAR_SEARCH_PORT -jar /usr/local/jetty/start.jar`
2. In your Dockerfile, add lines:
   `ADD api_startup.sh /api_startup.sh 
   RUN chown jetty:jetty /api_startup.sh 
   CMD ["/api_startup.sh"]`
3. Now you can run it like this:
   `docker run -it -p 80:80 -e MY_VAR_SEARCH_PORT=80 mydockerhubrepo/myimageid`

Comment: Awesome, thanks for your quick response! I’ll try it over the next couple of days and see if it works for me!

Comment: I actually ended up changing the way I packaged my project to use xerial pack and a docker file and that ended up solving my problem for me. I really appreciate you taking the time to put this up for me though! If I get back to using sbt assembly later I will definitely give it a go!